# Motion of charge particle in perpendicular electric and magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields

What happens when a particle is released from rest in radially outward electric field and magnetic field perpendicular to the plane of radially electric field?
(Not released from center)
I would like to know if it's possible to find out its equation or not.

Comment: What do you think will happen? Please don't ask people to solve a problem but ask about your specific uncertainty or confusion related to the problem

Comment: I think it will be a cycloid type motion around a circle but i want its equation

Comment: it is explained in        physicstask      website